# Parse issue with latex2exp

Tags: r

I am using latex2exp to add formulas in axis labels of ggplot2 graphs.

The following axis text works fine:

`latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2}(\\mu atm)$")`

A space is needed before the opening parenthesis. Not surprisingly, the following does not help:

`latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2} (\\mu atm)$")`

The following throws an error although `\\~` does add space in another label:

`latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2}\\~(\\mu atm)$")`

Original string: Measured $pCO_{2}~(\mu atm)$

Parsed expression: paste('Measured ','pCO',phantom() [ {paste('2')} ],~,,,,'(','',mu,,,,'atm',')','','')
Error in parse(text = str) : :1:53: unexpected ','
1: paste('Measured ','pCO',phantom() [ {paste('2')} ],~,
^

So, how can I add this space? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\phantom` macro:

```
latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2}\\phantom{x}(\\mu atm)$")
```

produces this in a title:

[image: screenshot]

You can experiment with other kinds of LaTeX spaces:

```
latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2}\\,(\\mu atm)$") # thin space
latex2exp::TeX("Measured $pCO_{2}\\;(\\mu atm)$") # thick space
```